# Passing "value type" as default second argument to template

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a template for class which takes as 1st argument some STL container (string,vector,list) and 2nd argument is operator< by default. I figured out that in  is less so I tried to implement it. Problem is that I am not able to get T2 which should be the T's "value type" (string -> char,vector -> T, list -> T)

```
template <typename T, typename C = less<T2> > // using T as T2 leads to error in
                                              // conversion from 'char' to 'const char *'
                                              // (for string as T)
class MyClass
{
  ...
   public:
       CIndex ( const T& x, const C& comp = C ()) {}
  ...
}
```

What is solution to thi? To be argument of less dependent on type T? Thank you very much for your help, I am not much experienced with templates

Comment: Where is `T2` declared? It is supposed to be part of the template? or is it a separate type?

Comment: I think you mean the value type (the type of the elements in the container), not the allocator type (a lot more complicated). In which case using `typename T::value_type` where you have T2 might work.

Comment: [Corrected](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23030992/revisions) your title to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the container's `value_type`:

```
template <typename T, typename C = less<typename T::value_type> >
```